# Accessibility: browser navigation with JS

Tags: accessibility, wcag

I have a page with list of items. each item is a link to go to the specific item info page. on that page there's a button called 'Delete'. so when a user click on it, this item is deleted and the user is taken back to the previous page.
since the 'Delete' button is a button and not a link, i'm not sure how accessible is to navigate the user a way from the page he was on.

when the user is taken back, there's a banner saying "item blah blah was deleted'. is that enough? do i need to warn the user BEFORE he goes back to the previous page?

Answer (score 1):

That could potentially fail [WCAG 3.2.2 On Input](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/consistent-behavior-unpredictable-change.html)

> **3.2.2 On Input:** Changing the setting of any user interface component does not automatically cause a change of context **unless the user has been advised of the behavior before using the component.**

Note the last part of that requirement (bold font added).  If your button says something like "Delete this link and return to previous page", then you'd be ok.

Upon returning the previous page, is the banner automatically read?  That would be another issue you'd have to address.  If a banner appears on the same page the user is viewing, then [`aria-live`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live) could be used to have the banner read to screen reader users.  But in your case, since you are returning to the previous page, you would either have to update the banner when the user returns (and use `aria-live`), or you would have to move the focus to the banner so that it's read (using `tabindex="-1"` and `focus()`).